# how to use facebook access token that has already been saved in my database to post on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I used the facebook api to collect users facebook long-lived access token on my website and saved them in a database. now I want to retrieve them from the database and post on their wall. however I received the following error message:

> Facebook SDK returned an error: You must provide an access token.

they have already given me the necessary permissions and I have provided access token from database

code:

```
<?php



 define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/');
    require_once(__DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '***************',

'app_secret' => '***************',

'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',

]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email','publish_actions','manage_pages','publish_pages']; 
// optional
$query = 'SELECT * FROM music_promotion';
$stmt = mysqli_query ($dbc,$query);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = $row['fb_access_token'];

try {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {

        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

    } else {

        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

    }

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\facebookResponseException $e) {

    // When Graph returns an error

    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

    // When validation fails or other local issues

    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;

}

if (isset($accessToken)) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    } else {

        // getting short-lived access token

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler

        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one

        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client-
>getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    }


    try {

        //Post property to Facebook


        $linkData = [
            'link' => 'the link',
            'message' => 'the message'
        ];
        $pageAccessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

        try {
            $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

        // When Graph returns an error

        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

        session_destroy();

        // redirecting user back to app login page

        header("Location: ./");

        exit;

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

        // When validation fails or other local issues

        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

        exit;

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to post to user timelines? Then you are not allowed to specify the message for the user to begin with, they have to type that in themselves.

Comment: I have publish_actions permission

Comment: That has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill